# Стоит ли реализовывать IEnumerator для перебора своей коллекции или класса если есть foreach?

Tags: c#

Стоит ли реализовывать IEnumerator если есть foreach?
на уроке разбирали вот такой пример:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class MyInt : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
    {
        int[] ints = { 12, 13, 1, 4 };
        int index = -1;

        // Реализуем интерфейс IEnumerable
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }

        // Реализуем интерфейс IEnumerator
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (index == ints.Length - 1)
            {
                Reset();
                return false;
            }

            index++;
            return true;
        }


        public void Reset()
        {
            index = -1;
        }

        public object Current
        {
            get
            {
                return ints[index];
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MyInt mi = new MyInt();

            foreach (int i in mi)
                Console.Write(i+"\t");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

потом пошли примеры подобные этому,и потом споры на счет того что IEnumerator не нужно реализовывать ,так как есть foreach,и мы в данных примерах можем использовать foreach(и некоторые говорят что так даже лучше).Пришли к мнению что лучше задать вопрос здесь

Comment: В смысле? Уточните вопрос, он какой-то мутный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интерфейс `IEnumerator` представляет перечислитель,с помощью которого становится возможен последовательный перебор коллекции, например, в цикле `foreach`.А интерфейс `IEnumerable` через свой метод `GetEnumerator` предоставляет перечислитель всем классам, реализующим данный интерфейс.Поэтому интерфейс `IEnumerable (IEnumerable<T>)` является базовым для всех коллекций.
**Если требуется создать класс**, содержащий объекты, перечисляемые в цикле `foreach`, то в этом классе следует реализовать интерфейсы `IEnumerator и IEnumerable`.
А этот ваш пример который вы копировали [отсюда](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level12/12_19.php)

> Советую вам читать внимательно и полностью, чтобы понять суть `IEnumerator` и `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 3):

Вы должны реализовать `IEnumerable<T>`, если ваш класс *является* коллекцией. Обычно такое не нужно, разве что вы изобретаете новый тип коллекции.

В нормальных ситуациях у вас есть объекты, и вы кладёте их в один из стандартных контейнеров. Например, в `List<T>`. При этом вам не нужно ни о чём заботиться, т. к. за энумерацию отвечает код того, другого объекта. Таким образом, у вас получается использовать `foreach` без того, чтобы кодировать `IEnumerable`.

Если же вы собираетесь заводить собственную, нестандартную коллекцию (а такое нужно очень редко), то вам и правда необходимо реализовать `IEnumerable`, но лучше — типизированный `IEnumerable<T>`.

---

При этом обратите внимание, что совмещение `IEnumerable` и `IEnumerator`'а в одном объекте — не такая простая задача. Дело в том, что `IEnumerator` хранит состояние обхода коллекции, в то время как один и тот же `IEnumerable` может одновременно обходиться в различных циклах.

Например, вот такой код:

```
MyInt mi = new MyInt();

foreach (int outer in mi)
{
    Console.WriteLine("outer: " + outer);
    Console.Write("inner: ");
    foreach (int inner in mi)
        Console.Write(inner + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

выдаёт бесконечную последовательность:

```
outer: 12
inner: 13 1 4
outer: 12
inner: 13 1 4
outer: 12
inner: 13 1 4
outer: 12
inner: 13 1 4
outer: 12
inner: 13 1 4
outer: 12
inner: 13 1 4
outer: 12
inner: 13 1 4
outer: 12
inner: 13 1 4
```

и т. д.

Правильнее было бы завести энумератор отдельно:

```
class MyInt : IEnumerable<int>
{
    class MyIntEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
    {
        public MyIntEnumerator(MyInt mi) { enumerable = mi; }

        int index = -1;
        MyInt enumerable;

        public int Current
        {
            get { return enumerable.ints[index]; }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public void Dispose() {}

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (index < enumerable.ints.Length - 1)
            {
                index++;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            index = -1;
        }
    }

    int[] ints = { 12, 13, 1, 4 };

    // Реализуем интерфейс IEnumerable
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MyIntEnumerator(this);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Проверяем на том же тестовом коде, получается:

```
outer: 12
inner: 12 13 1 4
outer: 13
inner: 12 13 1 4
outer: 1
inner: 12 13 1 4
outer: 4
inner: 12 13 1 4
```