# C# вопрос по интерфейсу IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, классы, ienumerator

Есть некая коллекция, в ней реализован интерфейс IEnumerable

```
 public class Proggresion : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private readonly int _itemCount;
    private int current;
    private int poss;
    public Proggresion(int a)
    {
        this._itemCount = a;
        current = 1;
        poss = 0;
    }
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (poss < _itemCount)
        {
            yield return current;
            current += 3;
            poss++;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Вопрос первый : не понимаю вот этой строки:

```
return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();//((IEnumerable)this) - не понимаю эту строчку, это какое-то преобразования что - ли?
```

Вопрос второй:

 Так же существует другая версия коллекции, которая работает аналогично, только уже в этой версии создан отдельно класс ProggresionIttetator, который реализует интерфейс IEnumerator.

```
 public class Proggresion : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private readonly int _itemCount;
    public Proggresion(int a)
    {
        this._itemCount = a;
    }
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ProggresionItterator(_itemCount);
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class ProggresionItterator : IEnumerator<int>
{
    private readonly int _itemCount;
    private int possition;
    private int current;
    public ProggresionItterator(int _itemCOUNT)
    {
       this. _itemCount = _itemCOUNT;
        this.current = 1;
        this.possition = 0;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (possition > 0)
        {
            current += 3;
        }
        if (possition < _itemCount)
        {
            possition++;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        possition = 1;
        current = 0;
    }
    public int Current
    {
        get { return current; }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```

Не могу понять разницу между двумя версиями, а так же разницу между IEnumerable и IEnumerator. Заранее спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: Второй пример — это демонстрация того, во что разворачивает первый пример компилятор, вроде

Comment: Читайте тут о `IEnumerable и IEnumerator`   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/813027/194837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `IEnumerable<T>` является потомком от `IEnumerable` => нужно реализовать и наследуемые методы, а именно обычный `IEnumerable`
2. "Разделяй и властвуй". Если логика реализации итератора имеет много кода, то имеет смысл ее выделить в отдельный класс, что бы не засорять основной.

Comment: `вы обязаны реализовать и этот интерфейс` - мне просто не понравилась формулировка, ведь реализация `IEnumerable<T>` сама по себе подразумевает реализацию `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 0):

1. `(IEnumerable)this)` преобразование текущей коллекции(`Progression`) к `IEnumerable`. ЕМНИП, каждая реализация `IEnumerable<T>` при операциях с ней возвращает именно интерфейс, например:

   ```
    // здесь тип List<int>
   var mylist = new List<int>{ /* какие то данные */};
    // здесь тип будет уже IEnumerable<int>, а не List<int>
   var myenumerable = mylist.Where(/*какое то условие */);
   ```

   Предположу, что здесь дело вероятней в этом, оттуда и преобразование.
2. Интерфейс [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) имеет метод `GetEnumerator()`, возвращающий ссылку на другой интерфейс - [`IEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx), который определяет функционал для перебора внутренних объектов в контейнере(в вашем случае `int`). То бишь конкретный элемент контейнера.

Comment: `ЕМНИП, каждая реализация IEnumerable<T> при операциях с ней возвращает именно интерфейс` - `mylist.Where` - Where - это метод расширения, он никак не связан с реализацией `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Спасибо за замечание.